# Applying Quotes Across Multiple Lines in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016, ssms-2016

Is there a keyboard function that applies single quotes across a list of values? I have 10 IDs that I have copied from an Excel spreadsheet and I would like to execute a query that uses an IN clause on this list, and I don't want to manually add single quotes and comma around each item.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE someValue IN (
ABC1
ABC2
ABC3
ABC4
)
```

I want to highlight the values and using a keyboard shortcut turn the list into:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE someValue IN (
'ABC1',
'ABC2',
'ABC3',
'ABC4'
)
```

I got how to get quote in the beginning using SHIFT + ALT (select the list and type single quote **'**)
Courtesy: [Link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/96371/applying-quotes-across-multiple-lines/96378#96378?newreg=5c3f55c24a924dd28cd9834ad8a625ae).

But how to do the same at the end of each item to add a single quote and comma (**',**)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the cursor behind where you want to edit, press alt, then click and drag down.  In your example you would place the cursor after the ABC1. click and drag till you get to ABC3.  Then type ',

Answer (score 0):

You can do in the following way:

1.Add text to the beginning of each line

```
Ctrl+H
type “^” in the “Find”
type text you want to add in “Replace with”
Choose the “Regular expressions” checkbox
```

2.Add text to the end of each line

```
Ctrl+H
type “$” in the “Find”
type text you want to add in “Replace with”
Choose the “Regular expressions” checkbox
```

OR You can follow this link for detail https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bradchen/2016/09/21/add-text-to-beginning-or-end-of-each-line-using-ssms/